# Is it possible to host an A100 40 GB PCIe accelerator on a Dell PowerEdge R740?

Tags: gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, dell-poweredge

We have a Dell PowerEdge R740 server. Is it possible to mount inside it a A100 40GB PCIe Nvidia accelerator?

Comment: The Nvidia card requires PCIe Gen4.

Comment: Indeed. But PCIe gen4 is backward compatible with ver 3, so, aside from bandwidth reduction, the physical connection can be done. My main concern is related to physically fitting the accelerator (I did not get it yet) into the server case.

Comment: It's a double slot but space shouldn't be a problem. The server has many PCIe slots.